# How to fill an array of structs in a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to create an array of a structure in an external function "add", and print it's fields, but when I get back to the main function "arr" it is still NULL. 
I'm confused because I've been creating arrays in external functions many times and it worked.. probably this time the dynamic memory allocation is messing the things up. Can I please get an advice on this matter?
Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
    char* id;
    char gender;
    char *name;
}Member;

void add(Member arr[], int size);
void print(Member arr[], int *size);

int main()
{
    char temp[100];
    int size=0;
    Member *arr = NULL;
    Member *data = (Member*)malloc(sizeof(Member));
    //scan fields
    gets(temp);
    data->id = (char*)malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(data->id, temp);
    gets(temp);
    data->gender = temp;
    gets(temp);
    data->name = (char*)malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(data->name, temp);

    add(data, &arr, &size);
    print(arr, &size);
    return 0;
}

void add(Member *data, Member arr[], int *size) 
{
    arr = (Member*)realloc(arr, (*size + 1) * sizeof(Member));
    arr[*size] = *data;
}

void print(Member arr[], int *size)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < *size;i++)
    {
        puts(arr->id);
        puts(arr->gender);
        puts(arr->name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you're not actually passing an array, but only a pointer to the address of its 0th element, and like any other pass-by-value, the function gets its own local copy of that pointer.

Comment: Never ***ever*** use the `gets` function. It's [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), and has therefore been removed from the C specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead (but be aware of the differences).

Comment: There are also many other problems in your code, like for example the assignment `data->gender = temp`, which should generate a compiler warning.

Comment: There is a mismatch between the caller and the callee. The caller correctly passes the address of the pointer, but the callee takes the pointer (and should take its address so it can modify the pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int i){
  i++;
}

int main(){
  int i = 3;
  f(3);
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

We all know that `f()` incremented its *local copy* of `i`, not the variable that was passed into `f()` to initially set that value.  With that having been said, let's take another look at your `add()`:

```
void add(Member *data, Member arr[], int *size) 
{
    arr = (Member*)realloc(arr, (*size + 1) * sizeof(Member));
    arr[*size] = *data;
}
```

When `arr` is passed into the function, it contains a memory address of the current `arr`, which starts as NULL.  But just like when we change the local value of `i` in `f()` above, setting `arr` to a new value within `add()` only changes the local value; it does not change `main()`'s `arr`.

We also know that if we pass a function an *address* of data we want it to change, the function can then change the data at that *address* and the data at that address will reflect the change in the calling function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int * i){
  *i = *i + 1;
}

int main(){
  int i = 3;
  f(&i);
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

The same logic applies ( though it gets more confusing) when you want to change a *pointer*'s value; send that *pointer*'s address!  Let's start with a very simple case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int** i){
  *i = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  **i = 99;
}

int main(){
  int *i = NULL;
  f(&i);
  printf("%d\n", *i);
}
```

Here we create a pointer to an `int` in main, and initialize it to NULL.  Then we send the address *of that pointer* (that is, the address we stored the NULL) to `f()`, which (like in your program) allocates some memory and puts the address of the newly allocated pointer _at the address of main's `i`.  Now, the data stored at `&i` has changed, and dereferencing `i` from `main()` will dereference the newly allocated address.

In your code, just as in mine, you'll have to change the way you're passing `arr` to `add()` as well as how you interact with it - an exercise you'll get the most out of thinking through yourself.  But in short, something like this should get you started:

1. pass `add` `arr`'s address, not the address it stores.
2. Store new address of reallocated memory back to the same address, that is, `&arr`
3. make sure to update `add()` to dereference the pointer to a pointer *twice* to set the member at the address stored at the address `&arr`.

Comment: Thank you Dan for pointing out the issue. Can you please explain how to fix this? should I send a pointer to the array to change it's value globally?

Comment: in short yes.  I'm adding some detail for you.

Comment: `int i = f(3);` is a bit nonsensical in your first example -- given you declare `void f(int * i)`... (the compiler won't let you do that)

Comment: yeah, that first example didn't actually get run through a compiler.  Fixed.

Comment: I knew what you meant, but poor Boris was probably a bit confused...  Sometimes it helps to step back and start with "What's a pointer?" (e.g., *A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the address of something else as its value. In other words, a pointer points to the address where something else can be found.*) and then going forward with why you need to pass the address of the original pointer to insure the function doesn't simply receive a copy-of-the-pointer (with a very different address of its own -- pass-by-value)

Comment: Thank you DavidC.Rankin and Dan Farrell, I appreciate your help.